# is there a possibility to run sys.dm_exec_sql_text in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Does any know if this query can be converted and run in sql 2000

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.TEXT like '%sp_OACreate%'
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Voted to migrate this to dba

Comment: **No** - the new DMV (Dynamic Management Views) are a **new feature** in SQL Server **2005** - high time to upgrade!!

Comment: darn, but wasnt there another way to get the list of queries that are being run in sql 2000 server, after all profiler can see all that

Comment: You may be thinking of [`fn_get_sql`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1008/sql-server-statements-currently-running-with-fngetsql/). However the query you've listed above doesn't get "the list of queries" that are running - it shows the set of queries that *have* been run... and I don't believe there was any equivalent in SQL Server 2000. Agree with @marc_s - time to upgrade. `sp_who2` can get you part way there, but there was no cross apply then, so you'd have to loop through, and the odds are the last query wouldn't still be running by the time you got to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT 
      spid
    , login_time
    , last_batch
    , [status]
    , loginame
    , [db_name] = DB_NAME([dbid])
    , (SELECT [text] FROM ::fn_get_sql(sp.[sql_handle])) Command 
FROM [master].dbo.sysprocesses sp 
WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for late reply I had figured this exact code out few days ago....Thanks a lot...I will mark your answer as correct one though